# chalk.bgHex is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, chalk

I'm using [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) version ^1.1.3

No idea why it's saying that the method is not recognized:

```
const chalk = require('chalk'),
  _ = require('lodash'),
  info = chalk.yellow,
  green = chalk.green,
  script = chalk.bgHex('#ebd2f8')
```

Error: `chalk.bgHex is not a function`

I also don't know how I'd append a text color on top of that background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit that introduced `hex/bgHex` was committed just [2 hours ago](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/commit/cb3f2308e17cd2878d2722db7762bdc725e9ff48). There hasn't been a new publish to the NPM repository with that commit.

If you want to use it, you can use the GitHub-hosted version of the module:

```
$ npm i chalk/chalk
```

However, do so with extreme caution. There's probably a reason why the developers haven't published a new version yet (i.e. it's not finished).

Comment: how can I tell when it's published finally to npm?

Comment: @DarkMatter I guess you should check https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk to see when it gets a version bump (although that doesn't necessarily have to mean that a newly published version contains `bgHex`).